# Как написать скрипт, выводящий периодически в складывающем окне слова на английском и его перевод и затем закрывающий его?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю по немного js и наткнулся на такое странное задание, с одной стороны интересное, с другой не понятное.

> Написать скрипт, выводящий периодически в складывающем окне слова на
>   английском и его перевод и затем закрывающий его.

Вопрос таков:

- Как это понять?
- Как это сделать?

Comment: ну и нам тоже не понятно. Без контекста особенно, что такое _в складывающем окне_

Comment: @ThisMan вот и я думаю об этом уже который час, надеюсь сообщество поможет в это вопросе)

Comment: @ThisMan а это скорее всего косяк перевода в книге, или откуда там задание взято. Автор, где выкопали такую задачу? Там какое нить `fold` было, и вместо раскрывающегося/всплывающего получилось складывающееся.

Comment: @teran [14 задча](http://compunets.narod.ru/labs.html)

Comment: по моему `html 4.0` появился еще в прошлом тысячелетии, стоит ли по нему выполнять лабораторные работы?

Comment: @teran для интереса, стоит! Я же не по html 4.0 выполняю  задание, а по js

Comment: Тогда понимайте так: "скалывающийся = всплывающий/раскрывающийся/модальный" и т.п. _как сделать_ - Периодически - значит по таймеру, заготовить массив слов и переводов. Показать окно, вывести пару слов, закрыть окно через промежуток времени.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал вот так)

```js
var notransl = ["Яблоко", "Привет", "Пока", "Слово", "Мир", "Машина"];
var transl = ["Apple", "Hello", "Bye", "Word", "World", "Machine"];

function call() {
  popup = window.open("trnsl.html");
  setTimeout(wait, 8000);
}

function caller() {
  setInterval(call, 12000);
}

function wait() {
  popup.close();
}

function showMessage() {
  var x = Math.round(Math.random() * (notransl.length - 1));
  var y = Math.round(Math.random() * (notransl.length - 1));
  if (x == y) {
    y = Math.round(Math.random() * (notransl.length - 1));
  }
  document.write('<br>' + notransl[x] + " - " + transl[x]);
  document.write('<br>' + notransl[y] + " - " + transl[y]);
}
```

```css
html, body{
 width: 100%;
 height:  100%;
}
```

```html
<body onload="showMessage();">
```